# How to align multiple charts with different data

Tags: highcharts

I have three pie charts displayed in a row. Two have two segments, one has five. All three have vertical legends.

Given that, the chart with five segments displays the pie slightly smaller, due to the extra height of the legend. It also has a slight negative vertical offset.

Is there any way I can set all three charts to render the chart in the same position? I've tried setting the center to 50%,50% in plotOptions, didn't help.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue update this to show issue http://jsfiddle.net/goar1xL8/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `marginBottom`-Value of the chart to a value that is equal an all charts. Highcharts is trying to display the pie as big as possible, therefore it will use more space if the legend is not as big.

By setting the `marginBottom` you force the chart to ignore the actual legend size.

The `center: ['50%','50%']` setting will only take into account the actual plot area. So if this area is decreased because of a taller legend it has no effect.

I made a jsfiddle where you can explore this settings:

http://jsfiddle.net/doc_snyder/dsmgy6ts/